# WPF: About SourceInitialized and ContentRendered

Tags: wpf

Can someone tell me some scenarios that we use this kind of events for the `Window` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you need to do something with Win32 window's handle. The `SourceInitialized` event provides the best way to handle situation when this handle is available for the first time. I used the `SourceInitialized` to hook `HwndSource` window procedure to apply my own logic for Windows messages processing.